# CSS Stop Hover on Button Border

Tags: css, hover, border

I have the below website:
http://test.peterstavrou.com

See where the Border line highlights on hover?
I want to disable the hover on the outer line and make it blue

I still want to keep the hover on the inner circle bit.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look, This may not be the right answer based on the code i could inspect.

What i did was this

```
<p>
<a href="http://victradeshall.com/cititec.com.au/managed-services/">
<i class="icon-3x fa-puzzle-piece extra-color-2" style="border: 1px solid #2AC4EA;">
<!--<i class="circle1-border"></i>-->
</i>
</a>
</p>
```

That seemed to get the border to have a fixed color and disable a hover effect on the border while the hover effect inside the ring worked as normal.